# Fetch a value of SQLalchemy instrumentedattribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I fetch the value of a `InstrumentedAttribute` object in SQLalchemy:

```
(Pdb) ResultLine.item_reference_1
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x793dc90>
```

The above statement prints me the sqlalchemy object.

What I actually need is the value associated with it.

Answer (score 12):

There is no value associated with an `InstrumentedAttribute`; you are looking at a table *declaration*, not a result set. `InstrumentedAttribute` is used to define a relationship to another table, for example.

Query the database for results, and the resulting objects will have the reference filled in for you:

```
 for res in session.query(ResultLine).filter(somefilter):
     print res.item_reference_1
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have a specific item, you can get the value like this:

```
line = session.query(ResultLine).first()

column = ResultLine.item_reference_1  # this is InstrumentedAttribute

key = column.key  # "item_reference_1"

value = getattr(line, key)
```